# c# create a popup without using Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have seen other apps do this, but can't figure out how it is done.  I have a Form and clicking a button shows another Form, but it appears as two on the task bar.

I want a "popup" that does not do this task bar thing (as that has certain user repercussions).

Can I make the popup part of the first form.  I realise I can add a panel to my form and bring it to front, but I want this popup to be outside my app's form.

How do I do this?

Comment: Does not have this task bar thing: Use `ShowInTaskbar = false`, then it'll not show in the task bar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `Form` has an property called `ShowInTaskbar` if you set this to `false` in your Popup Form, your Taskbar shows only one window.

[MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.form.showintaskbar(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Just added the MSDN article for "ShowInTaskbar", glad to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can always hide your pop up form by setting `this.ShowInTaskbar = false;`.